# Vectorizing nearest neighbor computation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, vectorization

I have the following function which is returning an array calculating the nearest neighbor:

```
def p_batch(U,X,Y):
    return [nearest(u,X,Y) for u in U]
```

I would like to replace the for loop using numpy. I've been looking into numpy.vectorize() as this seems to be the right approach, but I can't get it to work. This is what I've tried so far:

```
def n_batch(U,X,Y):
    vbatch = np.vectorize(nearest)
    return vbatch(U,X,Y)
```

Can anyone give me a hint where I went wrong?

**Edit:**

Implementation of nearest:

```
def nearest(u,X,Y):
    return Y[np.argmin(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(u,X)),axis=1)))]
```

Function for U,X,Y (with M=20,N=100,d=50):

```
U = numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState(123).uniform(0,1,[M,d])
X = numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState(456).uniform(0,1,[N,d])
Y = numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState(789).randint(0,2,[N])
```

Comment: Share the implementation of `nearest` or are you importing it from some library/package? Also, for performance, you can look for other ways than `np.vectorize`.

Comment: Only if you show us `nearest`, `U`, `X`, and `Y`.

Comment: `np.vectorize` is probably never the right approach. I guess a [KD-tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) yould be better, at least it says so in the documentation: "kd-tree for quick nearest-neighbor lookup"

Comment: @Divakar nearest implementation added!

Comment: @aryamccarthy: I have added them in the original question!

Comment: @MSeifert Isn't `Kd-tree` within an array's own space? Would it work between two arrays?

Comment: `vectorize` feeds scalar values to your function.  If you want it to treat just `U` that way, then use its 'exclude' parameter on the others.  This and other details are explained in its docs.

Comment: Also, on performance, quoting from the docs on `np.vectorize` for completeness - `"The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."`

Comment: @Divakar Yes, but I didn't knew they were from different arrays back then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You could use [`Scipy's cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) to generate all those euclidean distances and then simply use `argmin` and index into `Y` -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

out = Y[cdist(U,X).argmin(1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [76]: M,N,d = 5,6,3
    ...: U = np.random.mtrand.RandomState(123).uniform(0,1,[M,d])
    ...: X = np.random.mtrand.RandomState(456).uniform(0,1,[N,d])
    ...: Y = np.random.mtrand.RandomState(789).randint(0,2,[N])
    ...: 

# Using a loop comprehension to verify values
In [77]: [nearest(U[i], X,Y) for i in range(len(U))]
Out[77]: [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

In [78]: Y[cdist(U,X).argmin(1)]
Out[78]: array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

**Approach #2**

Another way with [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min.html) to give us those `argmin` indices directly -

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise

Y[pairwise.pairwise_distances_argmin(U,X)]
```

---

Runtime test with `M=20,N=100,d=50` -

```
In [90]: M,N,d = 20,100,50
    ...: U = np.random.mtrand.RandomState(123).uniform(0,1,[M,d])
    ...: X = np.random.mtrand.RandomState(456).uniform(0,1,[N,d])
    ...: Y = np.random.mtrand.RandomState(789).randint(0,2,[N])
    ...:
```

Testing between `cdist` and `pairwise_distances_argmin` -

```
In [91]: %timeit cdist(U,X).argmin(1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.2 µs per loop

In [92]: %timeit pairwise.pairwise_distances_argmin(U,X)
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.6 µs per loop
```

Timings against loopy version -

```
In [93]: %timeit [nearest(U[i], X,Y) for i in range(len(U))]
1000 loops, best of 3: 298 µs per loop

In [94]: %timeit Y[cdist(U,X).argmin(1)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.6 µs per loop

In [95]: %timeit Y[pairwise.pairwise_distances_argmin(U,X)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.1 µs per loop

In [96]: 298.0/55.6   # Speedup with cdist over loopy one
Out[96]: 5.359712230215827
```